# Customized title for alertAction ios

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to create a customized title for the `alertAction` of an `AlertController`, with conditional function depending on the state of different `switches`:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: “Got it”, message: “Please, select:”, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


name01: String = "name01"
name02: String = "name02"
name03: String = "name03" 

if switch01.on {
        let action01 = UIAlertAction(title: name01, style: .Default) { (_) in }
    }
    if switch02.on {
        let action02 = UIAlertAction(title: name02, style: .Default) { (_) in }
    }
    if switch03.on {
        let action03 = UIAlertAction(title: name03, style: .Default) { (_) in }
    }



    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (_) in }

    alert.addAction(action01)//Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UIAlertAction'
    alert.addAction(action02)//Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UIAlertAction'
    alert.addAction(action03)//Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UIAlertAction'
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)//No error
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `action0n` are not valid outside the `if swith0n.on{}`. They do not exist. => `if swith0n.on{let action0n = ...  alert.addAction(action0n)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `Action` of `AlertController` out side the `if` block because out side the `if block` they are not available to access, also use if condition to just decide the title like this way.

```
name01: String = "name01"
name02: String = "name02"
name03: String = "name03" 

if switch01.on {
    name01 = "Title Chanhed"
}
if switch02.on {
    name02 = "Title Chanhed"
}
if switch03.on {
    name03 = "Title Chanhed"
}
let action01 = UIAlertAction(title: name01, style: .Default) { (_) in }
let action02 = UIAlertAction(title: name02, style: .Default) { (_) in }
let action03 = UIAlertAction(title: name03, style: .Default) { (_) in }
alert.addAction(action01)
alert.addAction(action02)
alert.addAction(action03)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
```

Also if you want to perform action on title basis you can compare title like this way inside action handler.

```
let action01 = UIAlertAction(title: name01, style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in 
     if action.title == "name01" {

     }
     else {

     }
}
```